# Aggregate program that lists the updates to all of the programs on your system that needs updating?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-7, update, automatic-updates

Does this exist for windows? Imagine having a program that lists all of the updates you need to do to a windows system, that would be powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several apps that do this to a limited degree.

[FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/)

[Update Notifier](http://cleansofts.org/view/update-notifier.html)

[CNet TechTracker](http://www.cnet.com/techtracker/) (registration reqd)

I use FileHippo which tracks most of the apps I use. None of these are really "enterprise" tools though, if you are looking to do this on a larger scale than just a handful of PCs, you're probably looking for something like [Altiris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altiris), which is hugely expensive and absurdly complicated.

Comment: Good stuff, I didn't even know this existed!

Answer (score 0):

Another handy one is [Secunia PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/), this lists programs with security Vulnerabilities (switch to advanced mode to see a full list.